# gregexpr function in R returning different results whether Perl is TRUE or FALSE

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I have the following piece of HTML I'm trying to run regex on with gregexpr function in R

```
<div class=g-unit>
<div class=nwp style=display:inline>
<input type=hidden name=cid value="22144">
<input autocomplete=off class=id-fromdate type=text size=10 name=startdate value="Sep 6, 2013"> -
<input autocomplete=off class=id-todate type=text size=10 name=enddate value="Sep 5, 2014">
<input id=hfs type=submit value=Update style="height:1.9em; margin:0 0 0 0.3em;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id=prices class="gf-table-wrapper sfe-break-bottom-16">
<table class="gf-table historical_price">
<tr class=bb>
<th class="bb lm lft">Date
<th class="rgt bb">Open
<th class="rgt bb">High
<th class="rgt bb">Low
<th class="rgt bb">Close
<th class="rgt bb rm">Volume
<tr>
...
...
</table>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the table part from this html by using the following regex expression

```
<table\\s+class="gf-table historical_price">.+<
```

When I run the gregexpr function with perl=FALSE it works fine and I get a result
However if I run it with perl=TRUE I get back nothing. It doesn't seem to match it

Does anyone know why the results are different from just switching Perl on and off?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [You should not parse HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/725418). Use a parser instead.

Comment: I cannot readily obtain the content as posted, but to build on @TLP, something like this (using the XML package):  doc <- htmlTreeParse('your countent URL', useInternal = TRUE) ;       
xpathSApply(doc, "//divclass='gf-table historical_price']//th", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in the extended mode for regex, [the dot is able to match newline characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_04), that is not the case in perl mode. To make it work in perl mode, you need to use the `(?s)` modifier to make the dot able to match newline characters too:

```
> m <- gregexpr('(?s)<table\\s+class="gf-table historical_price">.+</table>', str, perl = TRUE)
```

In many regex flavors, the dot doesn't match newlines by default, probably to make more handy a line by line job.

The `s` in the inline modifier `(?s)` stands for "singleline". In other words, this means that the whole string is seen as a single line (for the dot) even if there are newline characters.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the inline [`(?s)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) modifier forcing the dot to match all characters, including line breaks.

The `perl=T` argument switches to the ([**`PCRE`**](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)) library that implements regex pattern matching.

```
gregexpr('(?s)<table\\s+class="gf-table historical_price">.+</table>', x, perl=T)
```

However as stated in the comments, a parser is recommended to do this. I would start out using the `XML` library.

```
cat(paste(xpathSApply(htmlParse(html), '//table[@class="gf-table historical_price"]', xmlValue), collapse = "\n"))
```